# Change "Other User" from Windows 10 login?

Tags: windows, windows-10, desktop-customization, login-screen

I have `Do not display last user name` enabled using [Local Security Policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjy6v.png).

I prefer it that way for a few reasons one being I'm not the only one to use the computer.

However I was wondering if there was any possible way to **change the text from "Other User".**

Here is a screenshot of my login page (ignore the fact there's a different background):

[image]

Comment: Change it to what exactly? Just some other random text, or ???

Comment: I don't see how that's _too_ relevant, but for my case I would want it to say something that describes the computer system the people are logging into. Could also be useful for other reasons, haven't thought that far though.

Comment: Knowing what you want it to display could change your question's scope greatly.  Regardless, there is not easy way to change it AFAIK; it's part of the OS.  So you'd probably have to hack at system files to get it changed, which is almost always a bad idea(tm). :)

Comment: Hmm. I wouldn't be opposed to trying! Hopefully someone's done it already and can provide insight.

Comment: Did anyone come up with a solution for this? In an educational lab setting, "other user" doesn't really make any sense. A welcome message or no text at all would be ideal.

Comment: @p_q Agreed. But no I haven't found a solution. Feel free to up vote the question

Comment: @Insane already did. I'll be sure to respond here if I find anything. It has to be stored somewhere.... We edit the default picture just by editing the default gray person image. Seems like the process for changing the text wouldn't be too dissimilar.

Answer (score 1):

The file you want to edit is:

```
C:\Windows\System32\en-US\credprovhost.dll.mui
```

You will need to grant yourself modify permissions and use a dll file editor to change `string 100` from `Other User` to *something else*
You can do this via GPO if it's for work. Just be sure to fix the permissions after you make your changes.

Comment: I will try this soon!